# How can I transform my dict in Json object?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples

I'm new in Python, and I'm trying to encode in Json an data dict.

My dict is :

```
data = { ('analogInput', 18) : [('objectName','AI8-Voltage'),
                                ('presentValue',238.3),
                                 ('units','Volts')],
         ('analogInput', 3)  : [('objectName','AI3-Pulse'),
                                ('presentValue',100),
                                ('units','Amp')]
        }
```

And when i'm trying to do : foo = json.dumps(data)
I've got this message : Fatal error : keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple

I'm trying to search answers, but I dont understand how i can do proceed in my case

Thanx you any answers

Comment: JSON only allows object keys to be strings, numbers, or booleans. You can't have multi-element keys like `('analogInput', 18)` in JSON.

Comment: You'll need to use something Python-specific, like Pickle.

Comment: Or redesign your data so that it doesn't need tuples as keys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all types can be used for JSON keys.

> Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, Boolean or null).

For more information, take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp).

Now as feasible solution, I recommend you to implement two functions that converts your tuples to string and converts your strings to tuple. A quite simple example is provided below:

```
import json
data = { ('analogInput', 18) : [('objectName','AI8-Voltage'),
                                ('presentValue',238.3),
                                 ('units','Volts')],
         ('analogInput', 3)  : [('objectName','AI3-Pulse'),
                                ('presentValue',100),
                                ('units','Amp')]
        }


def tuple_to_str(t):
    # It can be implemeneted with more options
    return str(t[0])+'_'+str(t[1])


def str_to_tuple(s):
    l =s.split('_')
    # Your first (second) item is int
    l[1] = int(l[1])
    return tuple(l)


if __name__=="__main__":
    # create a space for a dict of data with string keys
    s_data= dict()
    for key in data:
        s_data[tuple_to_str(key)] = data[key]

    x = json.dumps(s_data)

    # create a space to load the json with string keys
    raw_data = json.loads(x)

    final_data = dict()
    for key in raw_data:
        final_data[str_to_tuple(key)] = raw_data[key]

    # Ture
    print(final_data)
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. I will check this and try to understand the way you use

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit. In a Python dict, the key can be any *hashable* type, including a tuple, a frozen set or a frozen dict (but neither a list, nor a set or a dict).

But in a Json object, dictionary keys can only be strings, numbers (int, or float), booleans or the special object None.

Long story short, your input dictionary cannot be directly converted to Json.

Possible workarounds:

- use an different serialization tool. For example, pickle can accept any Python type, but is not portable to non Python application. But you could also use a custom serialization format, if you write both the serialization and de-serialization parts
- convert the key to a string. At deserialization time, you would just have to convert the string back to a tuple with `ast.literal_evel`:

  ```
    js = json.dumps({str(k): v for k,v in data.items()})
  ```

  giving: `{"('analogInput', 18)": [["objectName", "AI8-Voltage"], ["presentValue", 238.3], ["units", "Volts"]], "('analogInput', 3)": [["objectName", "AI3-Pulse"], ["presentValue", 100], ["units", "Amp"]]}`

  You can load it back with:

  ```
    data2 = {ast.literal_eval(k): v for k,v in json.loads(js).items()}
  ```

  giving `{('analogInput', 18): [['objectName', 'AI8-Voltage'], ['presentValue', 238.3], ['units', 'Volts']], ('analogInput', 3): [['objectName', 'AI3-Pulse'], ['presentValue', 100], ['units', 'Amp']]}`

  You can just see that the json transformation has changed the tuples into lists.